# how to float button more than center and less than right?

Tags: css

I am struggling to place a button at a absolute position. When I use `float:right`, Its too much for me , I also used `position:absolute and right:350px` however this gives me problem in resizing the browser.

So How can I place my button such that I can use float:right minus certain space?

Comment: parent of absolute div should be positioned relative.

Comment: float: right; margin-right: 100px;

Comment: Or you use `calc`